# How to set a div with li to parents height

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have ben boxing with this issue for ages now.

I have a parent `div` "wrapper" containing a child `div` "sidebar-wrapper" consisting of an `ul` with `li` in it.

I want "sidebar-wrapper"s height to fit "wrappers" height. My issue is when i set its `height` to `auto` goes 0.

My HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
   <!-- Sidebar -->
   <div id="sidebar-wrapper">
       <ul class="sidebar-nav">
           <li class="sidebar-brand">
               <a href="#">
                   a lit of these li's
               </a>
           </li>
       </ul>
   </div>
   <!-- Page Content -->
   <div id="page-content-wrapper">
       <div class="container-fluid">
           <div class="row">
               Whatever Content!!
           </div>
       </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

My css:

```
#wrapper {
    overflow:auto;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    width: 100%;

    min-height:400px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
#sidebar-wrapper {
    margin-left: -150px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    background: #000;
    height:400px;
    float:left;
    background-color:#222222;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
#page-content-wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 15px;
}
.sidebar-nav li {
    text-indent: 20px;
    line-height: 40px;
}
.sidebar-nav li a {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #999999;
}
```

Comment: what is that you actually want??? didnt get you..

Comment: I want my child div's height to fit the parrent's height. Question updated. ty.

Comment: which one is the child div and the parent div???

Comment: Sry for the bad question. I have updated the question again.. 'Wrapper' is the parent. 'sidebar-wrapper' is the child.

Comment: ok..got it..will update you soon with a solution..

Comment: is [this](http://jsfiddle.net/lalu050/f4enLod9/) what you want???

Comment: put these in your css..`html,body{
    height: 100%;
}` and in `#wrapper` add `height: 100%;`..also add `height: 100%;` in `#sidebar-wrapper`

Comment: setting height to auto just sets the height equal to the height of the contents of the div..here i think you want the height to be equal to the wrapper..so you'll have to set it to 100%.

Comment: exacly Lai. But if i set the sidebar-wrapper to 100% the background-color colapses and i can only only see the li's. And now the wrapper's heigth is set to contentviews height.

Comment: what do you mean by "it collapses and it is only the li's i can see" ??

Comment: oh,,you checked in my fiddle right??? thats because you have `margin-left: -150px;`..if you remove that, it will be like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/lalu050/f4enLod9/6/)..

Comment: Im not familiar with fiddle but you can see the result at http://madsgadeberg.dk/Home/Projects here you can see thet the left menubar is larger than the black border which is the wrapper.

Comment: "left menubar is larger than the black border which is the wrapper" ???what is that???? please explain it a bit more clearly..

Comment: Ok. The black border you see is the "wrapper". The left "menu" with Dashboard, shortcut, etc is the sidebar-wrapper. The "simple sidebar" is the page-content-wrapper

When i set wrapper's height to Auto, and both content and sidebar's height to 100%. Then my sidebar-wrapper exceeds the wrapper and the wrappers height follows content-wrappers height.

Comment: ok..give `height:100%` to `html,body` and `body-content`..this will solve your problem..try it..

Comment: I got the exact same result. :/

Comment: did you try @Mads ???

Comment: oops..give `height: 100%;` to #wrapper too..

Comment: Yes i did.. serval times. I can easily see the logic behind what you guys are saying. It just dont work.

Comment: Ok.. now the Wrapper fits the whole window ofc. and my sidebar-wrapper stretches to wrapper.

Comment: this is what i can see..http://i.imgur.com/3VSYi45.png

Comment: That is also almost right. But instead of stretching to 100% of window i would like wrapper to have the height if the largest div. Sidebar or content wrapper.

Comment: yes of. ty for your help. I really appreciate it!

Comment: le clearfixe misique.

Answer (score 1):

### See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lalu050/f4enLod9/)

The CSS used is as follows

```
html,body{
    height: 100%;
}

#wrapper {
    overflow:auto;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    min-height:400px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
#sidebar-wrapper {
    margin-left: -150px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    background: #000;
    height:100%;
    float:left;
    background-color:#222222;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
#page-content-wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 15px;
}
.sidebar-nav li {
    text-indent: 20px;
    line-height: 40px;
}
.sidebar-nav li a {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #999999;
}
```

I've given `height:100%` for html,body,wrapper and body-content..

Setting height to auto just sets the height equal to the height of the contents of the div..here i think you want the height to be equal to the wrapper..so you'll have to set it to 100%.

and this is how can i see your website after making the specified changes..

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Change the sidewrapper height to 100% and give the wrapper a height: see fiddle: [See fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9h0xq48a/2/)

```
#wrapper {
        overflow:auto;
        border: 1px solid #000000;
        width: 100%;
        height: auto; /* example height */
        -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
        -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
        -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
        transition: all 0.5s ease;
    }
    #sidebar-wrapper {
        margin-left: -150px;
        overflow-y: auto;
        background: #000;
        height:100%;
        float:left;
        background-color:#222222;
        -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
        -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
        -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
        transition: all 0.5s ease;
    }
    #page-content-wrapper {
        width: 100%;
        position: absolute;
        padding: 15px;
    }
    .sidebar-nav li {
        text-indent: 20px;
        line-height: 40px;
    }
    .sidebar-nav li a {
        display: block;
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #999999;
    }
```

Comment: The wrapper's height need to be dynamic based on the height of sidebar and content wrapper.

Comment: Updated fiddle and previous comment, add height auto to the wrapper div to have it set a dynamic height.

Comment: Also, your content-wrapper has a position absolute set, this will have a result of the height in that wrapper not being calculated.

Comment: My sidebar-wrapper still get the heigth from the wrapper. And the wrapper ofc gets it from contentview. As it was set to fill.

Answer (score 0):

Set the parent div's position to relative and children div's to absolute:

```
#wrapper {
   ...
   ...

    /****  added css   ****/
     position:relative;
    /*********************/
   ...
   ...
}
```

**Edit 1**

as you commented, I came to learn that you want the sidebar to available throughout the page regardless the height of the page.

If that is the case then "wrapper" div has nothing to do with.
Just set the position of "sidebar-div" to "fixed" and give proper top and bottom margins according to your page header and footer margins:

and set the **top** and **bottom** of child wrapper to 0:

```
#sidebar-wrapper {
   ...
   ...
    /****  added css   ****/

    position:fixed;
    top:10px;
    bottom:10px;

    /*********************/
   ...
   ...
}
```

Here's the updated demo JS fiddle link:

**<kbd>[Updated Demo JS Fiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/sunnykumar08/6g2vz2ad/4/)</kbd>**

Hope that helps!

Comment: If i do so then my SidebarWrapper is limited by the Wrappers height. as if the page-content-wrappers height desides everything.

Comment: why do you actually want page-content-wrapper to decide the height of everything?

Comment: I guess you just want a sidebar to be available throughout the page content regardless of the height... is that what you want?

Comment: Yes. my sedebar shall always be visible.

Comment: great, check my edited answer. Just play with "sidebar-div" and not with wrapper. Position it fixed and set the top and bottom margins... and you're done.